# how to convert comma seperated numbers from textbox to alphabets

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a Textbox which displays the value as 10,20,30, i.e

```
 textbox1.text="10,20,30,50"
```

Predefined values: `10-A, 20-B, 30-$, 50-*`

I want the value displayed in `label1` is according to `textbox1` value, so now according to this `textbox1` values the

```
Label1.text="AB$*"
```

I want to write the code for this in Vb.net (asp.net)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  We'd be happy to help.  Unfortunately, your question, as it is currently written, is not a good fit for this site.  It's too broad.  Which part of this task are you having trouble with?  What have you tried and in what ways did it not work?

Comment: For what it's worth, I would recommend using the `String.Split` method to get all the numeric codes from the string.  Then I'd use a `For Each` loop to loop through the codes.  Then I'd use a `Dictionary` to look up the equivalent alphabet letter for each of the codes.  You, of course, would need to first populate the dictionary with the codes and equivalent values that you want to use in the translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in c#

```
string textboxval=textbox1.text;
string[] words = textboxval.Split(',');
foreach (string word in words)
 {
    int no=int.parse(word);
    switch(no)
    {
     case 10:
       label1.text += "A";
       break;
     case 20:
       label1.text += "B";
       break;
     case 30:
       label1.text += "$";
       break;
     case 50:
       label1.text += "*";
       break;
    }
 }
```

in vb

```
Dim textboxval As String = textbox1.text
Dim words As String() = textboxval.Split(","C)
For Each word As String In words
Dim no As Integer = Integer.parse(word)
Select Case no
    Case 10
        label1.text += "A"
        Exit Select
    Case 20
        label1.text += "B"
        Exit Select
    Case 30
        label1.text += "$"
        Exit Select
    Case 50
        label1.text += "*"
        Exit Select
End Select
Next
```